# Understanding Server Set-up for Using ImageMagick and PaperClip with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, imagemagick, paperclip

I am new to Ruby on Rails (coming from C#/ASP.NET).  My question is about the server related changes that happen when using PaperClip and ImageMagick. I followed a tutorial to learn how to use PaperClip.  So when I installed ImageMagick on my laptop Mac OS in order to use the PaperClip gem, things seemed pretty straight forward.

Obviously that means that ImageMagick is installed on my local machine during development, before the push to production on Heroku.  Is anything put in my Ruby app for ImageMagick (code, config changes, etc.)?  When I push my Ruby app to Heroku, things just seem to work for both ImageMagick and PaperClip.

How and where are the ImageMagick installed components pushed up to Heroku?  ImageMagick is not a gem so I am just trying to understand how local development installed software like ImageMagick is transferred to production environments like Heroku.

Is ImageMagick installed, in addition to the PaperClip gem, on the Heroku server (or any server for that matter) when I do the Heroku push?  Just trying to understand the use of installed software like ImageMagick vs gems and how things are pushed to production environments and integrated with the app "automagically" working after the push to production.

I want to understand how this works so I can deploy on different server environments (e.g. Rackspace instead of Heroku) and I want to understand what I have to manually install/set-up vs install to get things working.  I hope this makes sense.

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer (I couldn't bring myself to read your prose) is to realize that Rails runs on Ruby, which means it harnesses the [`gem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) system of the language

When you install gems, there are two things you have to consider. Firstly, most gems are "internal" to Ruby only; meaning they will provide functionality for API's or something programmatic; The second bunch of gems work with *third party software* - such as MYSQL or ImageMagick

When you use a gem which *interfaces* with other software, that software needs to be installed (so the gem can use it). This is where the problems start to occur for many people using ImageMagick

--

**Paperclip**

You must remember that `Paperclip` is *not* dependent on ImageMagick to run

From the Paperclip [github repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip):

> Paperclip is intended as an easy file attachment library for Active
>   Record. The intent behind it was to keep setup as easy as possible and
>   to treat files as much like other attributes as possible. This means
>   they aren't saved to their final locations on disk, nor are they
>   deleted if set to nil, until ActiveRecord::Base#save is called. It
>   manages validations based on size and presence, if required. It can
>   transform its assigned image into thumbnails if needed, and the
>   prerequisites are as simple as installing ImageMagick (which, for most
>   modern Unix-based systems, is as easy as installing the right
>   packages). Attached files are saved to the filesystem and referenced
>   in the browser by an easily understandable specification, which has
>   sensible and useful defaults.

Paperclip can work exclusive to ImageMagick to manage the uploaded images. ImageMagick is an "optional extra", allowing you to crop / edit images on the fly. Like `ffmpeg` (the video equivalent to ImageMagick), you can run Paperclip on its own

If you want to crop images etc - you'll have to install the library files for ImageMagick on your system. This is simple on Linux, *much* trickier on Windows

--

**Heroku**

We're very fortunate in that Heroku is designed to give RoR a stable environment to run with. That said, Heroku does this by providing as much functionality as possible - including the ability to install `ImageMagick` on the system

Heroku runs linux on Amazon's AWS infrastructure. This means it's relatively simple to use ImageMagick with it - you just need to add it to your gemfile & Heroku will handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the `Gemfile` located at the root of your Rails application. In there you should have all the Gems used by your application. This file is used by `bundler` Gem; when you want to deploy the application on a new machine, you don't have to install Gems one-by-one. Just run `bundle install` and the bundler take care of the Gems.

In Heroku, this is automatized. After `git push` to heroku, it is doing necessary steps, like `bundle install`, `rake db:migrate`, etc.

Please note there is an additional file, `Gemfile.lock`, contains Gems with versions. This is to ensure that bundler on a new system will install the Gems with the same version as yours.